# How to use List with JDL entities in Jhipster

Tags: java, spring-boot, jhipster, jdl

I'm new to use Jhipster. I want to create a JDL entity using my existing model classes. Here is my model class.

```
@Data
public class ResponseJson implements Serializable {
    private List<String> names;
}
```

Normal JDL entity can be created like,

```
entity ResponseJson{
  names String
}
```

But I need to know **how to use List** in JDL entities.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot use List directly

Instead you can create a one-to-many relationship in order to make **ResponseJson** have multiple String by wrapping this String in another Object

Your JDL should be:

```
entity ResponseJson {
    ...
}

entity ObjectContainingString {
    name String
}

relationship OneToMany {
    ResponseJson{name} to ObjectContainingString{json}
}
```

Comment: Exactly this is what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to opt for a solution that is not using JDL, you can change you model to use a `List` like this:

```
public class ResponseJson implements Serializable {
    @ElementCollection
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<String> names = new HashSet<>();

    ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Jhipsters page on [Field types and validations](https://www.jhipster.tech/jdl/entities-fields#field-types-and-validations) discusses the available JDL types.

Currently, it does not support List, text[] etc directly.

For people who want to create entities having these types, one workaround is to make the entity with the types that Jhipster JDL offers and then use [Liquibase](https://www.liquibase.org/) to add the other fields types like List, text[] etc.